# Using vue router inside hosted vue microfontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vue-router, micro-frontend

I want to build a microfrontend project with react and vue3.
i'm using vue as a host.
i also have two routes inside react which is as a separated project.
so everything works fine without a doubt.
i can get the `remoteEntry.js` file, which is exposed form the react project webpack file and therefor i can get it in the vue,
but the main problem is that i do not know how to use vue router to navigate between those routes inside vue project which is as a host, or a container.

**these codes related to react is something like this:**

**App.tsx:**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/auth/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/auth/login/admin" element={<LoginAdmin />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**bootstrap.tsx:**

```
function mount(element: Element): void {
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(element);
  root.render(<App />);
}

if (isDev()) {
  const element = document.querySelector('#auth-service');

  if (element) {
    mount(element);
  }
}

export { mount };
```

**index.ts:**

```
import('./bootstrap');
export {};
```

**these codes related to vuejs is something like this:**

**Auth.vue:**

```
<script>
const AuthApp = require('auth/AuthApp');

export default {
  mounted() {
    AuthApp.mount(this.$refs._auth);
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="_auth"></div>
</template>
```

**App.vue:**

```
<script>
import AuthApp from './components/Auth.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    AuthApp,
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <AuthApp />
  </div>
</template>
```

**bootstrap.js:**

```
const app = createApp(App);
app.mount('#container-service');
```

Thanks for any helping.